# My textView text is not saving itself when i leave the cell

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to do something similar to Notes app and I am stuck with what i think is such a stupid thing. When i enter my app there is a add button to add new notes. I can then rename it and enter to a new view controller which consist of only title and textView on the whole screen. I use Codable and UserDefaults to save the data. Title is saving just fine, but whatever i type in textView and then come back to see all rows in tableView and i come back to that particular "note" all my typed text is gone.

This is my didSelectRowAt method

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Note") as? NoteViewController {
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            
            
            vc.bodyText = note[indexPath.row].body
            vc.titleText = note[indexPath.row].title
            
            if note[indexPath.row].title == "New note" {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Rename note", message: "Please enter name for a new note", preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addTextField()
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default))
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rename", style: .default) { [unowned self, ac] _ in
                    let newName = ac.textFields![0]
                    note[indexPath.row].title = newName.text!
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    vc.viewDidLoad()
                    self.save()
                    
                })
                present(ac, animated: true)
            } else {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

And my NoteViewController

```
class NoteViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    
    var bodyText: String?
    var titleText: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: .checkmark, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveNote))
        title = titleText
        textView.text = bodyText
        
        }
```

And Save()

```
 func save() {
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let savedData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(note) {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(savedData, forKey: "note")
        } else {
            print("failed to load data")
        }
    }
```

I tried changing my method didSelectRowAt by adding my save() to different places but it's only saving title.

Comment: What does your `save()` function look like?

Comment: @GRIV sorry for that, i added it so if you can take a look again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `onSavingTap` closure in the NoteViewController to pass the data back to the main view controller.

```
class NoteViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    var onSavingTap: ((String) -> Void)?

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    var bodyText: String?
    var titleText: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:   .checkmark, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveNote))
        title = titleText
        textView.text = bodyText
    
    }

    @objc func saveNote() {
        onSavingTap?(textView.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

then in the didSelectRow method you set the closure to update your data array as follows:

```
vc.onSavingTap = { [weak self] body in
    self?.note[indexPath.row].body = body
    self?.save()
}
```

Comment: really appreciate the help, it all works now